# How to get authentication key from ninjawallet?

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I am using this api https://ninjawallet.com/docs/payment-api/v1#payment-request

I wanted to set authentication API in one of my project But I didn't get signup into Ninja Wallet API.

```html
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ninjawallet.com/v1/ping');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer *************';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: you did sign up and get an API key, I presume?

Comment: @delboy1978uk I have edited the question actually he don't know where to get signup and the use API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment

**Login URL of Ninja Wallet :** https://ninjawallet.com/login

**Signup URL of Ninja Wallet :** https://ninjawallet.com/register

**Documentation of Ninja Wallet :** https://ninjawallet.com/docs/api

---

After login you just need to generate auth token. Please refer below image.

[image]